# Toggle onclick between ascending en descending date using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css-tables, usort

I have got this problem. I am trying to make a function where I can sort results by dates in a table. So far I got this:

```
function wedstrijdenClub (){

    $laMatches = WaterpoloAPI::call("Matches", "getMatches", Array(
        "",
        "",
        isset($_GET["ClubId"]) ? $_GET["ClubId"] : "",
        "",
        "",

    ));

        $asc = $laMatches;
        $desc = $laMatches ;

        // Sort Matches ascending
       usort($desc, function($a, $b) {
                       return stringToUnix($a->Date) - stringToUnix($b->Date);
       });


       // Sort Matches descending

       usort($asc, function($a, $b) {
                       return stringToUnix($b->Date) - stringToUnix($a->Date);
       }); 

    echo '<div class="asc">'.implode('<br />',$asc).'</div>' ;
   echo '<div class="desc">'.implode('<br />',$desc).'</div>' ;

    echo "<h6 id='rcorners' style='background-color:#3db7e4; padding: 1rem; color:white;'><strong>Wedstrijden</strong></h6>";
    echo "<table class='hover'>";
    echo "<tbody >";

    $lnToday = strtotime(date("d-m-Y"));                          
                          $lcCurrent = "";                        
       foreach($laMatches as $loMatch) {
           if(stringToUnix($loMatch->Date) < $lnToday) {
                if($lcCurrent != $loMatch->Date) {     



echo "<thead>";
echo "<tr >";
echo "<th class='text-center date'>";
echo "$loMatch->Date</th>";
echo "<th class='text-center'></th>";      
echo "<th class='text-center'></th>";
echo "<th class='text-center'></th>";
echo "</tr>";               



echo "</tr>
          </thead>";           
                }               
                $lcCurrent = $loMatch->Date;           
           }
    echo "<tr class='text-center'>";
        echo "<td >$loMatch->Time</td>";
        echo "<td>$loMatch->HomeTeam </td>";
        echo "<td><strong><a href='..\wedstrijd?MatchId=".$loMatch->Id."'>$loMatch->ResultHome - $loMatch->ResultGuest </a></strong></td>";
        echo "<td> $loMatch->AwayTeam</td>";
    echo "</tr>";   
    }

    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";



}
```

in my php page

```
<style> div.asc, { display:block ; } div.desc { display:none ; } </style>
    <div class="large-12 columns block asc"><?php wedstrijdenClub(); ?></div>
                <div class="large-12 columns block desc"><?php wedstrijdenClub(); ?></div>

                <a class="asc">Asc</a>
 <a class="desc">Desc</a>
```

and in my footer

```
<script>
jQuery(document).on('click','a.asc, a.desc',function(e){
e.preventDefault() ;
jQuery('div.block').hide() ;
jQuery('div.'+jQuery(this).attr('class')).show() ;
}) ;
</script>
```

Where I call a list of matches. It descent and ascent ...but I want it on a click event ...how I am going to do this? I am still learning ...so sorry if it is a silly question.

Comment: If you want to make an action on click, you need to do it in javascript.
You can for example display your 2 results un 2 differents divs : `<div class="asc" style="display:none;"><?php echo $asc_results;  ?></div>` and `<div class="desc" style="display:none;"><?php echo $desc_results;  ?></div>`, then have 2 buttons `<a class="asc">Sort ASC</a> <a class="desc"></a>`, and add JS : `<script>jQuery(document).on('click','a.asc',function(){ jQuery('div.asc').show() ; }) ;`

Comment: Thx Pierre for response! I will try that

Comment: but if both are display:none ...it shows nothing in the beginning just the button ...how am I suppose to display one at default

Comment: haven't seen such a mess in a long time... while sorting an array per key might have countless duplicate questions... these two arrays? `$asc` & `$desc` are the worst part of it; simply use one result array (takes half the RAM). also, generating HTML tables isn't too common anymore... while already using jQuery, it might be rather be the current practice, to send out JSON; e.g. `die(json_encode($results));`.

Answer (score 0):

The JS part you need is really simple i think :

```js
jQuery(document).on('click','a.asc, a.desc',function(e){
e.preventDefault() ;
jQuery('div.block').hide() ;
jQuery('div.'+jQuery(this).attr('class')).show() ;
}) ;
```

```css
div.asc, { display:block ; }
div.desc { display:none ; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<div class="block asc">A B C D E F</div>
<div class="block desc">F E D C B A</div>

 <a class="asc">Asc</a>
 <a class="desc">Desc</a>
```

Just be carefull with your php part : when you use usort function, the value of $laMatches is changed, so calling 2 times usort will only show you the last results.

You need to make copies of your $laMatches and sort the copies :

```
 $laMatches = Array('red','blue','green','brown','yellow') ;

    $asc = $laMatches ;
    $desc = $laMatches ;

   usort($desc, function($a, $b) {
                   return strlen($a) - strlen($b) ;
   });
   usort($asc, function($a, $b) {
                    return strlen($b) - strlen($a) ;
   });

   echo '<div class="asc">'.implode('<br />',$asc).'</div>' ;
   echo '<div class="desc">'.implode('<br />',$desc).'</div>' ;
```

Comment: thx Pierre for your answer! I edited my post .....but it shows nothing ...did I miss something?

Comment: If your print_r($laMatches) in your function are you sure there is something in it ? Can you also check the source page to see what it really display in html ?

Comment: Also be carefull in your footer, don't mix CSS and JS : `<script>
jQuery(document).on('click','a.asc, a.desc',function(e){
e.preventDefault() ;
jQuery('div.block').hide() ;
jQuery('div.'+jQuery(this).attr('class')).show() ;
}) ;</script> <style>
div.asc, { display:block ; }
div.desc { display:none ; }
</style>`

Comment: It still shows nothing ....when I do a print_r($laMatches) it shows me the data's so it's not empty. I edited the post where i put <style></style> part above the div in my main php.

Comment: i think there is something wrong with this part echo '<div class="asc">'.implode('<br />',$asc).'</div>' ;
   echo '<div class="desc">'.implode('<br />',$desc).'</div>' ; ?

Comment: So you can replace it with `echo <div class="desc"> ; print_r($desc) ; echo '</div>' ;`

Comment: when I clicked on desc ...it gives me the data of the matches

Comment: You mean it show the datas not organised in desc ? But the JS part is ok right ? So it's now just a problem of sorting data for $desc ? The rest is okay ?

Comment: well yes and no...it shows like you said....but the other div is not disappearing

Comment: Well can you add your actual code ? It's hard to see where you are now