# using link onClick() to switch value passed to function to sort database result order ASC or DESC

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a register.php page which pulls data from a database. I have the results listed on my php page and i have created links from the column headings to use to sort the columns.

the links look like this

```
<div class='col-sm-12 day-heading'>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2"><a id="student_forename" onClick="showUser('student_forename','ASC')">Forename</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><a id="student_surname" onClick="showUser('student_surname','ASC')">Surname</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><a id="club" onClick="showUser('club','ASC')">Club</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3"><a id="student_instructor" onClick="showUser('student_instructor','ASC')">Instructor</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-2"><a id="date_awarded" onClick="showUser('date_awarded','ASC')">Date</a></div>
    <div class="col-sm-1"><a id="student_age" onClick="showUser('student_age','ASC')">Age</a></div>         
</div>
```

showUser function is

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showUser(test, order) 
{ 
var users = document.getElementById('instructor').value;
var sex = document.getElementById('club').value
//var sort = document.getElementById('sortby').value;
var sort = test;

const but = document.getElementById(test);
if(but.getAttribute("onClick") === "showUser(test,'DESC')") 
{
    but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser(test,'ASC')");
}
else
{
    but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser(test,'DESC')");
}


var order = order;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajaxcall.php?student_instructor="+users+"&club="+sex+"&sortby="+sort+"&orderby="+order,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

the issue i believe is with trying to use the variable value which is being passed to the function within it. for example this line

```
const but = document.getElementById(test);
```

should replace test with the value being passed from the onClick link for example

```
const but = document.getElementById(student_forename);
```

but have i used test correctly in the above code?

again the same for

```
if(but.getAttribute("onClick") === "showUser(test,'DESC')")
```

test should be replaced with the value of "test" and not be set to test.

hope that makes sense :)

Comment: u may try these methods : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212066/toggle-onclick-between-ascending-en-descending-date-using-php

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately the methods used in that thread are not suitable for my issue.

Comment: The first step should be to identify **where** something goes wrong. You've tagged your question with JS, PHP, and MySQL, but haven't provided any PHP or MySQL code.

Comment: hi @NicoHaase, i apologise, i've just update the code as i have received help and am in the process of sorting the issue. the code was changed to focus specifically on the part that was the issue and not to confuse things further :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dirty method :
you may add a class to your tag 
initialy class="asc" and when click u check if class exist and set "let order= asc" and remove class form a tag
next click checks if class exist and if not , set "let order= desc" and add class="asc". 
u can easy toggle classes and variables

 
In this case u don't have to pass order param to ur function
u may also toggle onClick functions :

```
<a onClick="showUser('student_forename','ASC')">Forename</a>
```

```
<a onClick="showUser('student_forename','DESC')">Forename</a>
```

using JS

u may write something like this :

```
<button id="but" class="ASC" onClick="showUser('student_forename','DESC')">BUTTON
</button>
<script>
    function showUser(test, order)
    {
        const but = document.getElementById('but');
        if(but.getAttribute("onClick") === "showUser('student_forename','DESC')") 
        {
            but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser('student_forename','ASC')");
        }
        else
        {
            but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser('student_forename','DESC')");
        }
        order = order;
        test = test;
        console.log(`order= ${order}`);
        console.log(`test= ${test}`);

    }
</script>
```

and later in function body DO WHATEVER U WANT :)

i added 2 console.log to check if i get value passed to function

Comment: thank you oleevier, the toggle bit looks promising, how would i go about implementing that?

Comment: i'm getting somewhere now thank you :) it is working for a single link, but i have multiple. i know how to solve it in my head but don't know enough about js to implement it correctly. if i wanted to use a the value of "test" in my function to populate the code above like so. `code` const but = document.getElementById('test');
        if(but.getAttribute("onClick") === "showUser('test','DESC')") 
        {
            but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser('test','ASC')");
        }
        else
        {
            but.setAttribute("onClick","showUser('test','DESC')");
        }`code`

Comment: where test inputs the value of test that has been passed to the function

Comment: var sort = test; 
var order = ASC; dont know if i get your point coz english is not my native ;)   , like u did before  , your function did not change , just param u send to function changes // you can copy past your function after if/else block and should work

Comment: i put back : function showUser **(test, order)** / u can use code you wrote before , just add begining of function to change buttons attibutes

Comment: thank for your continued help, its much appreciated! i have updated the original question to help explain better. its the value stored in the test variable that i want to populate your code snippet with. so where you have student_forename i want to replace that value with the value of test. this will make the code work with multiple links and not just the student_forename link, hopefully :D

Comment: \`showUser(${test},'DESC')\`) try use backtics instead of "" and ${var} / im not sure if it will work , but u may try

Comment: if this solve ur problem u can vote my answer as satisfactory answer and close topic